# NextJs including JQuery and my own JQuery code, sometimes my code runs first and jquery not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating an app with nextJs, query I need to use jQuery and some files with jQuery code, so I'm adding it using the Head from nextjs, I put the jQuery include first and then my own file but, sometimes it seems as my code is loading before the jQuery code is fully loaded resulting in jQuery not found when my code try to execute:

This is my Head file

```
import React from 'react'
import { Header } from './'
import Head from 'next/head'

const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.min.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/plugins/isotope-docs.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
                <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            </Head>
            <div class="page-wrapper">
              <Header />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export { Layout }
```

Sometimes it works as a charm, sometimes I get this:

> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
>
> at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
>   at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
>   at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
>   at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6

and sometimes this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
>
> at plugins.min.js:1
>   at plugins.min.js:1
>   (anonymous) @ plugins.min.js:1
>   (anonymous) @ plugins.min.js:1
>
> isotope-docs.min.js:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>   at isotope-docs.min.js:32
>   at isotope-docs.min.js:32
>   (anonymous) @ isotope-docs.min.js:32
>   (anonymous) @ isotope-docs.min.js:32
>
> main.js:754 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   at main.js:754

What can I try to fix this?